# Uncaught exception 'apiAuthException' with message 'Error fetching OAuth2 access token, message: 'invalid_grant''

Tags: php, google-oauth

I am using Google OAuth2 script go get users logged in with his google+ account. Below is the code to get access token:

```
require_once 'src/apiClient.php';
require_once 'src/contrib/apiPlusService.php';
$client = new apiClient();
$client->setApplicationName("Google+ Login Application");
$client->setScopes(array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me'));
$plus = new apiPlusService($client);
if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
  $client->authenticate();
  $_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
  header('Location: http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
 }
```

and in `config.php` i am setting Client ID and secret as below:

```
 'oauth2_client_id' => 'XYZ',
'oauth2_client_secret' => 'ABC',
'oauth2_redirect_uri' => 'http://example.com/gplus/index',
```

When i log in via google+ account then at the time of redirect, i get below as exception:

```
Uncaught exception 'apiAuthException' with message 'Error fetching OAuth2 
access token, message: 'invalid_grant''
```

I looked upon many answers but was not able to get the solution, can some specifically tell where the problem is?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. The API used by me , itself had a problem. So, i googled more and found working APi.
Below is the link if anybody wants

```
http://www.sanwebe.com/2012/11/login-with-google-api-php
```

Thanks :)